# Image upload - JavaScript error TypeError: this.elements.container is null

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, image-upload, supee-8788

I've looked through several posts and haven't found anything that has worked.

This is a Magento 1.7.0.2 install. Has had all patches. The problem is that when I browse for and select an image file to upload, as soon as I hit the "Close" button on the file selector, I get the following JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: this.elements.container is null
```

It has to do with the Javascript file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js, specifically in the _handleUpdateFile function.

```
    _handleUpdateFile: function (file) {
        var replaceBrowseWithRemove = this.miscConfig.replaceBrowseWithRemove;
        if(replaceBrowseWithRemove) {
            document.fire('uploader:simulateNewUpload', { containerId: this.elementsIds.container });
        }
        this.elements.container
            [replaceBrowseWithRemove ? 'update':'insert'](this._renderFromTemplate(
                this.elements.templateFile,
                {d
                    name: file.name,
                    size: file.size ? '(' + this._getPluralSize(file.size) + ')' : '',
                    id: file.uniqueIdentifier
                }
            )
        );
    },
```

The client hasn't uploaded any new images in ages, so I don't know for sure when the problem started. I have a feeling it has to do with the 8788 patch.

I'm not sure how elements.container is getting set or why it's null. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.